# Click on primeng dropdown and p-table paginator dropdown moves the body of the page

Tags: click, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns, p-table

Version used 15.1.0

I am using primeng version 15.1.0. When I click on some of the primeng dropdown and p-table paginator dropdown, it pushed the body of the page

Tried solution mentioned below, but did not help

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10992

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Hello, can you provide a stackblitz?